# "bash: /usr/bin/ls: Permission denied" Arch linux

Tags: shell, ls

Today I discovered that the command ls to list files, only returns the error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ls: Permission denied
```

This happens for every directory I try and also when running the command as root. The alternative command 'dir' works without any problem.

It may be possible that the problem has started after messing around with libc symlinks last week. I've already removed them and and replaced them with the ones from my live USB stick, so this shouldn't be the problem anymore.

To which package does the ls command belong to and can it just be reinstalled using pacman?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it after reinstalling the coreutils,

```bsh
sudo pacman -S coreutils
```

Comment: That would fix `ls` and the other coreutils tools. If you ran a `chmod` across the whole `/usr/bin`, then there are potentially _other_ tools that also have the wrong permissions.